# How would I rotate a character based on their camera? (Roblox)

Tags: camera, rotation, roblox

In Roblox, your camera has a CFrame with a lookVector and so on. What I'm trying to accomplish is to detect when a player has pressed their right mouse button, and through a loop, rotate their character based on the CFrame of the camera until the button is released.

I've pretty much got it, but instead of rotating the character model, it turns the screen black and kills the player. I've seen this done in RPGs on Roblox before, so I know it's possible, and probably fairly easy. I've worked with CFrames quite a bit in the past, so I'm not sure why I'm having such a hard time with this.

After a couple hours of playing around with ideas and checking online, I thought I'd just ask the question to save time. What's the correct way to achieve this?

Edit: My bad, this is what I have so far. I fixed the black screen, but the player still just dies.

```
local UIS,Player,Camera,Character,MB2Down = game:GetService('UserInputService'),game.Players.LocalPlayer,workspace.Camera,script.Parent,false
local Torso = Character:FindFirstChild('Torso') or Character:FindFirstChild('UpperTorso')

UIS.InputEnded:Connect(function(Input)
    if Input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton2 and MB2Down then
        MB2Down = false
        Character.Humanoid.AutoRotate = true
    end
end)

UIS.InputBegan:connect(function(Input,onGui)
    if Input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton2 and not onGui then
        MB2Down = true
        Character.Humanoid.AutoRotate = false
        while MB2Down and wait() do
            Torso.CFrame = CFrame.new(Vector3.new(Torso.CFrame),Vector3.new(Camera.CFrame.p))
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: Updated with the code. Sorry, I didn't even think about it.

Answer (score 2):

You've almost got it, but let me take a slightly different approach to my solution. When the player presses the right mouse button, let's connect a function to the Heartbeat event that will update the character's rotation to the camera's. Also, we will rotate the HumanoidRootPart instead of the Torso/UpperTorso. The HumanoidRootPart is the PrimaryPart of the character model, and thus is the part we should manipulate if we want to manipulate the model as a whole.

The way we will lock the player's rotation to the camera is as follows:

1. Get the position of the character.
2. Get the rotation of the camera (by using arc-tangent and camera's look-vector).
3. Construct the new CFrame for the player using the position and rotation from steps 1 and 2.
4. Apply the CFrame to the character's HumanoidRootPart.

The following code is in a LocalScript and is placed under StarterCharacterScripts:

```
local userInput = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local character = script.Parent
local root = character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local camera = workspace.CurrentCamera
local dead = false
local heartbeat = nil


function LockToCamera()
    local pos = root.Position
    local camLv = camera.CFrame.lookVector
    local camRotation = math.atan2(-camLv.X, -camLv.Z)
    root.CFrame = CFrame.new(root.Position) * CFrame.Angles(0, camRotation, 0)
end


userInput.InputEnded:Connect(function(input)
    if (input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton2 and heartbeat) then
        heartbeat:Disconnect()
        heartbeat = nil
        humanoid.AutoRotate = true
    end
end)


userInput.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, processed)
    if (processed or dead) then return end
    if (input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton2) then
        humanoid.AutoRotate = false
        heartbeat = game:GetService("RunService").Heartbeat:Connect(LockToCamera)
    end
end)


humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
    dead = true
    if (heartbeat) then
        heartbeat:Disconnect()
        heartbeat = nil
    end
end)
```

Let me know if you need any clarification.